# Retrieve Taskbar Docking Position: result incorrect

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to determine which side the Windows Taskbar (System Tray?) is docked to - so I can position my popup window above/below/left/right of the taskbar.

I am using `SHAppBarMessage(ABM_QUERYPOS, &barData)` to obtain this information but it always returns `ABE_LEFT` for me when my taskbar is `ABE_TOP`.

What's going wrong? Maybe I cant use that function to determine it? Maybe my `APPBARDATA` params are wrong?

```
APPBARDATA barData;
barData.cbSize = sizeof(APPBARDATA);
barData.hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
barData.uCallbackMessage = 0;
//barData.uEdge = ABE_LEFT; 
//barData.rc = RECT{0,0300,300};
barData.lParam = (LPARAM)FALSE; 

SHAppBarMessage(ABM_QUERYPOS, &barData);

// barData.uEdge always equals ABE_LEFT
```

Comment: You're not checking the return values of either of the API calls. How do you know that `FindWindow` returns a valid HWND, or whether `SHAppBarMessage` is successful or not? The code you've posted is the equivalent of roulette: *I'll throw this out there, and maybe it works or maybe it doesn't.* You should **always** check the return value of API calls, and read the documentation to find out what those return values mean and how to find more info.

Comment: Also a best practice would be to zero out the struct with memset before passing it to a Win32 API call. But I'm sure that's not your issue

Comment: If just ask the monitor for the work area

Comment: @kcraigie Not really. Initializing declaration like this: `APPBARDATA barData = { sizeof(APPBARDATA) };` is the idiomatic way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've actually had issues with that not fully initializing the entire structure with some compilers, specifically around large ints not getting fully zeroed out. Not the kind of bug you want to run into in production. memset is safest

Comment: @kcraigie You've got to use a real compiler. It's not as though the language is in any way ambiguous. Anyway, I don't believe what you say. Can you prove me wrong?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree with you that it was a compiler bug. I was using an iffy toolchain for a reference embedded platform at the time. So I've stuck with memset ever since.

Comment: It's FUD to recommend that beginners don't trust the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using the wrong flag. The following works:

```
APPBARDATA barData {0};
barData.cbSize = sizeof(APPBARDATA);
UINT_PTR res = SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, &barData);
```

Comment: What if there are multiple monitors?